# substring based on a specific pattern

Tags: python, substring

I am very new to Python. I am trying to substring a specific pattern from a long string of txt. This specific pattern occur multiple times in the same txt. For example:

```
s = 'apple/gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk/pear apple/009456/pear apple/dsakjdaghdj/pear'
start = s.find('apple') 
end =   s.find('pear', start)
s[start:end]
```

This was my initial attempt. However, it only gives me the very first chunk of text, which is `'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'`; instead, I will also need `'009456'` and`'dsakjdaghdj'`.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish (or are searching for). Please [edit] and try to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The most fancy is with Regular Expressions, but I think you don't want to use it here.

So one solution will be to get rid of all the unnecessary elements in the string and then to split it. **You can do this in one hit:**

```
result = s.replace("apple/","").replace("/pear","").split()
```

Note that result is a Python list, composed out of three strings. You can iterate through this list to get each item separately, and then you can build a string by concatenating:

```
new_s=""
for each_result in result:
    new_s = new_s +  each_result + " "
new_s = new_s.rstrip() #to remove the last empty space
```

Another way is that you can just remove the unneeded elements in place:

```
new_s = s.replace('apple/', '').replace('/pear', '')
```